# Creating a jsPDF document in a Blazor application

Tags: javascript, c#, html, blazor, jspdf

I have seen examples of creating a function in a .js file and exporting a pdf using jsPDF libraries. However, all the examples I have seen are just hard-coded text wrapped in

or other text related tags and was wondering if it is possible to pass along Object References from server-side code in C# to these Javascript functions?

Example, I have this file in my **wwwroot** diectory:
**HtmlDocumentConverter.js**

```
export function generateAndDownloadPdf(htmlOrElement, filename) {
    const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF({
        orientation: 'p',
        unit: 'px',
        format: [2550, 3300]
    });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        doc.html(htmlOrElement, {
            callback: doc => {
                doc.save(filename);
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });    
}
```

In my razor file, I have html/css and Telerik library components implemented and using Objects and Parameters embedded in my @code block to dynamically populate some of the fields. Here is a mini example: (File was reduced for example purposes, there's alot of code here)
**EmployeeReport.razor**

```
@using SomeModels

@inject SomeInterfaces

<TelerikWindow Visible="@visible">
    <WindowContent>
        <div class="row m-top g-0">
        <div class="col-12 justify-content-end">
        <TelerikButton Visible="@(!isPrinting)" @onclick="DownloadPDF" Class="darkButton" Icon="FontIcon.Download">
            <text>Download</text>
        </TelerikButton>
            </div>
    </div>
        <!-- Area I want to print -->
        <div class="padded" @ref="ExportSection">
            <div style="max-width: 25vw">
                <img src="@(CommonService.GetEmployeeHeadshot(Employee.PictureLink))" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- More html/css, Telerik components -->
    <WindowContent>
</TelerikWindow>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EmployeeModel Employee { get; set; }

    ElementReference ExportSection;
    bool visible;
}
```

Is it possible to dynamically pass along server-side objects/code to client-side code?

I tried creating a HTML file and defining the PDF template but ran into the same issue where I could not find a way to pass along server-side code to it to generate the relevant info I need. Some of the css classes I implemented did not render appropriately when I downloaded the file.